# join a chopped up list with a specified delimiter

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, chunks

I have an unknown number of samples that always come in pairs e.g. `11 22` or `33 44`.

I store all of the samples in a list `[11, 22, 33, 44]` and then chop it up by pairs `[[11, 22], [33, 44]]` to get a nested list.

All this is to use the pairs and display them later on with a specified delimiter e.g. `11:22`.

I have this which does the job of aggregating data and splitting the list:

```
def chop_it_up(array, chunk):
    for i in range(0, len(array), chunk):
        yield array[i:i+chunk]

n_samples = int(input("Number of samples: "))

list_of_samples = []
for i in range(n_samples):
    list_of_samples.extend(list(map(int, input().strip().split(' '))))

chunks = list(chop_it_up(list_of_samples, 2))

print(':'.join(str(x) for x in chunks))
```

A sample input would be:

`26 34`
`78 94`
`51 130`

However, the last line of the code produces this:

```
[11, 22]:[33, 44]
```

While the desired output should be:

```
[11:22] [33:44]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're joining the list *representations*, where you want to rebuild this representation with a colon instead of a comma.

I would do the following (using an outer join with space to join the generated sublist representations):

```
chunks = [11, 22],[33, 44]  
print(" ".join(["[{}]".format(":".join(map(str,chunk))) for chunk in chunks]))
```

prints:

```
[11:22] [33:44]
```

explaining the core of the solution:

```
"[{}]".format(":".join(map(str,chunk))
```

converts each number of `chunk` to string (so `str.join` accepts it) and passes it to `str.format` since it seems that you want to preserve the square brackets in your alternate representation.

Answer (score -1):

I believe [Jean's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49243630/9310553) can be made even simpler:

```
>>> l = [11, 22, 33, 44]
>>> r = ["[{}:{}]".format(l[i], l[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(l), 2)]
>>> print(*r)
[11:22] [33:44]
```

This answer avoids using multiple `join` methods and uses a single list comprehension.

Comment: I assumed that the input data was `[11, 22],[33, 44]  ` not a flat list

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre is right, the data is a nested list (a chopped-up single list).

Comment: If printing the items as pairs is all you need, then you don't have to create the nested list.

Comment: @nisemonoxide I tried it out and it works just fine on a flat list, which actually saves some typing.